# Adding radio buttons onto a graph drawn in java using jfreechart or swing

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I need to add a radio button onto a graph that performs a specific action when it is selected. I have drawn the graph using jfreeChart in java. But I am unable to figure out a way to add a radio button onto that graph. Is it possible to do so? If not, is it possible to draw a line graph in swing and add radio buttons on top of it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't know about  jfreechart(i guess you can't) but in swing you can

Comment: Thanks. It would be great if you add some codes or some example links where a radio button is added inside a graph using swing, if possible for you. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a `ChartPanel` instance to add `JFreeChart` to your application. Try to set some `LayoutManager` e.g. `BoxLayout` or `BorderLayout` and just add the Radio Button to the panel with proper constraints to define desired position.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried that out. But this actually adds my jfreechart graph to my application using a ChartPanel and then I add the chartPanel to a JPanel. This is the opposite of what I intended to do. I actually needed to add a BoxLayout (with RadioButton) inside a chart(created by JfreeChart), with certain constraints. May be it is not possible. Is it possible to do so?